# yielded put action not dispatched to store in callback

Tags: typescript, react-native, generator, redux-saga

Edited code and explanation to make things more clear:

I have a saga that calls a (non saga) function that shows an alert to the user.
The function (Alerts.showInAppMessage) accepts an onTap function that would be called when the user taps the alert. I could not pass yield put(showReceiveDialog(false)) as a callback since it's a generator. However, I managed to get yield put(showReceiveDialog(false)) line to to be called after the user tap by saving a reference to the generator and calling .next() on it  (see below). 
Code is called in the expected order, however the action isn't dispatched to the store.

```js
 let showInAppTransactionGenerator: IterableIterator<any>;

function* showInAppTransaction(alert: PushAlert) {
  if (alert.body && alert.title){
    yield Alerts.showInAppMessage(alert.title, alert.body, () => {
      showInAppTransactionGenerator.next();
    });
    yield put(showReceiveDialog(false));

  }
}
```

Comment: How is `showInAppTransaction` called? You're sure it's being run through the saga middleware?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to skip the extra generator indirection and use the alerts callback to resolve a promise.

```
function showInAppMessage(title, body) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    Alerts.showInAppMessage(alert.title, alert.body, () => {
      resolve();
    });
  });
}
function* showInAppTransaction(alert: PushAlert) {
  if (alert.body && alert.title){
    yield call(showInAppMessage, alert.title, alert.body);
    yield put(showReceiveDialog(false));

  }
}
```

Comment: That does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
yield call(onTapTransactionMessage);
```

That is the way we call any function from within our sagas.

You'll probably need to change this as well:

```
yield call(navigation.navigate, ScreenName.ACTIVITY);
```

Comment: afaik call is used for async operation, onTapTransactionMessage() and navigation.navigate(ScreenName.ACTIVITY) are both synchronous. just for the heck of I tried using call but getting the same result (yield navigation.navigate(ScreenName.ACTIVITY); is never called)

Comment: ive edited the code to make the issue more clear. yield put(showReceiveDialog(false)) is called but no action is actually dispatched to the store. if I execute a plain function (not redux) like navigation.navigate(ScreenName.ACTIVITY), it works just fine. I think the issue is with access to the store in this context but I'm not sure how to tackle this.

Comment: What action are you trying to dispatch?

Comment: That looks like a function, not an action that would update the store. Where are you importing that function, or what is its code?